# How to deal with multiple input components in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm coding a functionality like to do task app, so the user can insert multiples  taks. That's a print of the system screen so far.

[image]

I passed hours trying to figure it out how to deal with each input text individually, including trying to implement similar solutions from stackoverflow.

```
export default class Task extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { cardID: '', description: '', list: [] }

    this.handleAdd = this.handleAdd.bind(this)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this)       
    this.refresh()
  }
  handleAdd = cardID => {
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: URL,
      data: {
        description: this.state.description,
        cardID: cardID
      }
    }).then(resp => this.refresh())
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, description: e.target.value})
  }

  handleEdit = Task => {
    axios.put(`${URL}/${Task._id}`, Task)
      .then(resp => this.refresh(this.state.description))
  }

  refresh() {
    axios.get(`${URL}?sort=createdAt`)
      .then(resp => this.setState({ ...this.state, description: '', list: resp.data }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
          <TaskCard title="Parceiros Chave" cardID='1' color='blue-violet'
            handleAdd={this.handleAdd}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}       
            handleEdit={this.handleEdit}
            description={this.state.description}
            list={this.state.list}
          />
        ....
      </Fragment >
    )
  }
}
```

That's my taskCard component

```
const TaskCard = props => {

  const renderRows = () => {
    const list = props.list || []
    return list.map(Task => (
      Task.cardID === props.cardID &&      
      <Form key={Task._id}>
        <Form.Group key={Task._id} controlId="formBasicEmail">
          <Form.Control key={Task._id} className='inputs-field' name={Task._id} type="text"
            value={props.list.find(x => x._id === Task._id).description}
            onKeyPress={event => {
              if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                props.handleEdit(Task)
                event.preventDefault()
              }
            }}            
          />          
        </Form.Group>
      </Form>      
    ))
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Col style={{ padding: '0px' }}>

        <Card className={props.class}>
          <Card.Body style={{ margin: '0px' }}>
            <Card.Title className={props.color}>{props.title}</Card.Title>
            {renderRows()}
            <Form>
              <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
                <Form.Control className='input-field' name={'description' + props.cardID} type="text" placeholder="Insira um registro"
                  value={props.description}
                  onChange={props.handleChange}
                  onKeyPress={event => {
                    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                      props.handleAdd(props.cardID)
                      event.preventDefault()
                    }
                  }}
                />
              </Form.Group>
            </Form>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </Col>
    </Fragment >
  )
}

export default TaskCard
```

I'm using only description to deal with all input field.

list array contains all the input values that comes from mongodb.
In my example, that's the list array content:

[image]

For example, how can I edit one input field value without affect the other one?

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: @SakoBu how to deal with each input text field individually, once this element is repeated. For example, how can I edit one input field value without affect the other one.

Comment: Have you tried creating a state for each text field?

Comment: @cullanrocks the number of text field will increase dinamically. Each task created is one text field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the state for all inputs in the parent component you need to have a state value for each individual input.

```
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, description: e.target.value})
  }
```

Is just overwriting any prior input value saved to state.

You need to do something like this:

```
state = {}

handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  }
```

So that each input has it's own value in the parent state

Comment: tks for take your time to help me. But what about to declare each `[e.target.name]` in the constructor?  It's not necessary?

Comment: @mr.abdo Yeah it shouldn't be necessary. React will add it to the state after it's created.

Comment: No, if you are using parent state to control all inputs your state object will be dynamic because you have a dynamic amount of inputs.  The values will get added on the fly

Comment: Once the task is added, I need to show this value and edit this value, How can I recover this value? In the print screen that I added, how can I get the value of the first text input (task 1), for example?

Comment: target its value in state.  state[value].  It would be the name of whatever you saved it to state under.  In your example you are just saving an array of objects.  You need to save each input's state to an object attribute so you can target that attribute.  I'd suggest reading the react docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html